# Complex Numbers: How to find the number of solutions of $z^3 + \overline{z} = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

Find the number of solutions of $z^3+ \overline{z}=0$.

I tried to write $z=x+iy$ and then expand $z^3$, but I am not getting anything from it.

Please help me out.

Comment: This is not a quadratic, it is a cubic

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please make your titles more specific to the problem you wish to solve.

Comment: Seems to me that writing $z=a+bi$ for $a,b\in \mathbb R$ works quite well.  Try that again.  You should get two equations which are easily solved together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way than writing $z = x + iy$ and expanding.

Follow these steps/hints:

1. Rewrite the equation as $z^3 = -\overline{z}$. What can you say about $|z|$?
2. In view of 1., how can you express $\overline{z}$ in terms of $z$?
3. Now how does the equation look like?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$z^3+ \overline{z}=0$ implies $|z|^3=|z|$ and so $z=0$ or $|z|=1$.

If $|z|=1$, then $\overline{z}=z^{-1}$ and so $z^3=-z^{-1}$. Thus $z^4=-1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your help now I get it.